# How to do an URL rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I don't know anything about rewriting URLs in a .htaccess file and can't seem to figure out how to do what I need to do.

I have URLs like this:

```
www.website.com/subdir/10-this-is-a-post
```

I have a single php file in subdir, index.php, and the code inside that file needs to pull content from the datebase based on the number at the beginning of the page name -- in this case, 10.

To further complicate things, there is a .htaccess file in the base directory (i.e. the parent directory of subdir), which has the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
Options -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>
```

Any advice on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will place everything after the /... to index.php/...

Example: /subdir/10-this-is-a-post

Will be rewritten to: /index.php/subdir/10-this-is-a-post

Use this to parse the segments:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately I need the index file in the subdir directory to handle the page requests. Is there any way to rewrite /subdir/10-this-is-a-post to /subdir/index.php/10-this-is-a-post ?

Comment: Yes in the rewrite rule just change the location of the index file: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/index.php/$1 [L]. Is subdir in /subdir/10-this-is-a-post and /subdir/index.php/10-this-is-a-post the same?

Comment: This is a quick guide to Mod_Rewrite for reference: http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewforum.php?f=12